# OS X - TodoApp with shortcut that can popup on any space/desktop?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, shortcut, desktop

I'm fairly new to the Mac world. I really **love** the multiple desktop feature.

Unfortunately, every todo application I've tried takes me to the regular desktop when I want to use them, or on their own desktop. I would like to have an app that could pop-up on top of the screen no matter where I am – like Spotlight when I press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

I'm not sure it is possible though, since it feels like each app in full screen mode takes control of the whole "shortcut space". But once again, I don't know anything about OS X.

Is it possible, and if so, is there a todo app I could use that would do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Wunderlist for Mac](https://www.wunderlist.com/). It has a feature called "Mac Quick Add" where you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, and you can quickly add a todo with spotlight-like interface, and it works on any active space as long as the app is open.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Things](https://culturedcode.com/things/) by Cultured Code has a quick entry feature that can be evoked with a keyboard shortcut from anywhere.

Differently from Wunderlist you don't need a subscription for advanced features.